How to use text from textbox in Operator class
I'm trying to create script\addon. Main idea is have ability to enter text in textbox, hit button -> rename object name and object data name at one. But I can't figure out how to use string property from my_new_name variable in OBJECT_OT_RenameOperator.
import bpy

class VIEW3D_PT_autoname_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    
    bl_category = "AutoName"
    bl_label = "AutoName Widget"
        
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        
        ob = context.object

        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(ob, "my_new_name", text = "New Name")
        
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("object.custom_rename_operator")
    
class OBJECT_OT_RenameOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Operator to rename the selected object"""
    bl_idname = "object.custom_rename_operator"
    bl_label = "Rename Object"
    
    my_new_name: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="New Name", default="NewName")

    def execute(self, context):
        obj = context.active_object
        obj.name = self.my_new_name
        obj.data.name = obj.name
     
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
    
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW3D_PT_autoname_panel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_RenameOperator)
    bpy.types.Object.my_new_name = bpy.props.StringProperty(default="MyNewName")

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VIEW3D_PT_autoname_panel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_RenameOperator)
    del bpy.types.Object.my_new_name

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```


You can either provide the property to the operator in the layout or access it inside execute directly.
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        
        ob = context.object

        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(ob, "my_new_name", text = "New Name")
        
        row = layout.row()
        op = row.operator("object.custom_rename_operator")
        op.my_new_name = ob.my_new_name

or
    def execute(self, context):
        obj = context.active_object
        obj.name = obj.my_new_name
        obj.data.name = obj.name
     
        return {'FINISHED'}

